# What's tangling instances of a createjs Sprite together?

Tags: html, animation, createjs, easeljs

We're converting Animate projects to HTML5, and it's dumping out code that creates multiple instances of a Sprite-type object. It's generating sprite definitions like this:

```
(lib.quarterback = function() {
    this.spriteSheet = ss["Page12_Canvas_atlas_"];
    this.gotoAndStop(11);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();
```

And, those being used multiple times like this:

```
// Quarter Back copy 1
this.instance_19 = new lib.quarterback();
this.instance_19.parent = this;
this.instance_19.setTransform(-16.1,-371.1);
this.instance_19._off = true;

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_19) /* snip! */ .to({_off:true},1).wait(51));

// Quarter Back copy 2
this.instance_20 = new lib.quarterback();
this.instance_20.parent = this;
this.instance_20.setTransform(-16.1,-371.1);
this.instance_20._off = true;

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_20) /* snip! */ .to({_off:true},1).wait(51));

// Quarter Back copy 3
this.instance_21 = new lib.quarterback();
this.instance_21.parent = this;
this.instance_21.setTransform(-16.1,-371.1);
this.instance_21._off = true;

this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_21) /* snip! */ .to({_off:true},1).wait(51));

// etc.
```

Everything form the *start* of these instances on the timeline, up through the snipped portion in the example, works OK. However, the only *one* instance of each Sprite (`quarterback` in this case) is successfully being removed from the timeline at/near the end. The others simply get "stuck" in the their last position.

We've proven that these instances are OK on their own -- removing all but any one of them shows the expected behavior. But, having more than one instance of any given Sprite seems to prevent them all from being removed.

**What's going on here?!**

Answer (score 0):

The following example will toggle the target off on frame 0, and then back on for frame 1. You can use the "visible" property to achieve the same effect.

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(target).to({_off:false}).wait(1).to({_off:true}).wait(1).to({_off:false});
```

In above code that target is a graphics, to hide/show we are using _off.

Even i got this issues i have solve by calling a function and hide the movieclip

```
this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_21).to({_off:true},1).wait(51).call(hideInstance,this));
function hideInstance()
{
this.instance_21.visible =false;
}
```